# Sencha Touch 2: store sync is not working as expected

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am building an app related to order pickup. I have a list where order items are listed. The app has to send PUT request to Rest API in order to update the record when user tap on the list (specially on a button with in list item). My problem is if i tap a button within a list item, it sends multiple PUT requests but i think it should be only one request at a time.

My item tap function:

```
 var store=Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('storeOrderItem');
 var index = store.findExact('orderitem_id', record.get('orderitem_id')),
     orderItem = store.getAt(index);

 //updating item store
 orderItem.set('order_picker_id',NCAPP.app.loggedInUser.user_id);
 if(NCAPP.app.currentWarehouse.is_main_store==0)
 {
     orderItem.set('pickup_status','picked@anotherlocation');
 }
 else
 {
     orderItem.set('pickup_status','picked');
 }
 store.setProxy({url:NCAPP.app.baseApiUrl+'/order/item/'+record.get('orderitem_id')});
 orderItem.setDirty(true);
 //updating with proxy (changes database)
 store.sync();
```

When i monitor in google chrome debug screen, I see request has been sent for three times. (the store is loaded with three items). How can I avoid the three request and only one request per item tap? thanks
[image]

Comment: You might want first to add console.log() in the beginning of this onTap hanlder to make sure it's called once

Answer (score 0):

You have to confirm first that the itemtap() is called only once and then from there call a function in controller

Add the itemtap listener in the list as below.

```
listeners: {
    itemtap: function(dataview, index, item, e) {
            this.up('xtype').fireEvent('controllerfn');

               }
               }
```